# EML file as attachment is not downloading using IMAP in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, email, imap, eml

I am using IMAP library in python to read an email inbox which is working file and i am downloading all my attachment successfully but when any .eml file is coming as attachment i got an error, pease help me how to download an eml file coming as attachment.

Comment: people aren't telepaths, they didn't see your traceback with error

Answer (score 1):

In-order to download an attachment such as `.png` from an email, the payload needs to be decoded using: `part.get_payload(decode=True).decode()`. However, from the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/email.message.html#email.message.Message.get_payload):

> If the message is a multipart and the decode flag is True, then None is returned.

The error you are seeing is caused because a `.eml` file is a multipart message. The parts consist of `message/rfc822` at the top level which holds all the email's details. Beneath will be single part messages such as `text/html` which holds the email's text etc...

To download this text into an `.html` or `.txt` file you need to `.walk()` through the parts of the `.eml` file - like you are doing on the original email to download the `.eml` attachment.

Here is a snippet of my code:

```
if msg.is_multipart():
    for part in msg.walk():
        # extract content type of email
        content_type = part.get_content_type()
        content_disposition = str(part.get("Content-Disposition"))

        if "attachment" in content_disposition:
            if content_type == "message/rfc822":
                # walk through the .eml attachment parts:
                for eml_part in part.walk():
                    # find the content type of each part:
                    content_type = eml_part.get_content_type()
                    if content_type == "text/html": # this type is not multipart
                        body = eml_part.get_payload(decode=True).decode() # get_payload() can be decoded

                        # can do what you need with the decoded body.
                        # in this case extract text and save to .txt or .html

            else: .....
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need to use EML Parser?
You can find the manual for eml-parser [here](https://pypi.org/project/eml-parser/).

Answer (score 0):

You can use it:

```
def _read(self):
    """Reads all emails and get attachments.

    Returns:
        Attachments.
    """
    self.mail.list()
    self.mail.select(self.select)
    self.mail.uid('search', None, 'ALL')

    self.uids = self.data[0].split()
    self.content_length = len(self.uids)
    self.attachments = []

     for uid in self.uids:
        self.result, self.email_data = self.mail.uid(
                'fetch', uid, '(RFC822)')
        self.raw_email = self.email_data[0][1]
        self.raw_email_string = self.raw_email.decode('utf-8')
        self.parsed_email = email.message_from_bytes(self.raw_email)

        for part in self.parsed_email.walk():
            if part.get_content_maintype() == 'multipart':
               continue

            if part.get_content_type() not in ['text/html', 'text/plain']:
               self.attachments.append({
                     'name':
                      part.get_filename(),
                      'content_type':
                       part.get_content_type(),
                       'bytes':
                       part.get_payload(decode=True)
                    })

        self.result = {'attachments': self.attachments}

     return self.result
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use my high level imap lib:

https://github.com/ikvk/imap_tools

```
from imap_tools import MailBox, MailMessage

# get .eml files attached to email messages from INBOX
with MailBox('imap.mail.com').login('test@mail.com', 'password', 'INBOX') as mailbox:
    for message in mailbox.fetch():
        for att in message.attachments:
            if '.eml' in att.filename:
                print(att.filename, len(att.payload))
```

Also you can parse .eml in place - see lib examples:
https://github.com/ikvk/imap_tools/blob/master/examples/parse_eml_attachments.py